# SQL injection error in Modsecurity logs in Plesk

Tags: wordpress, hosting, sql-injection, server-side-attacks

I am receiving the following error for 1 of my wordpress site running on a Plesk server.

```
[client 000.00.00.000] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase
 2). Pattern match "[\\\\[\\\\]\\\\x22',()\\\\.]{10}$|\\\\b(?:union
\\\\sall\\\\sselect\\\\s(?:(?:null|\\\\d+),?)+|order\\\\sby
\\\\s\\\\d{1,4}|(?:and|or)\\\\s\\\\d{4}=\\\\d{4}|waitfor\\\\sdelay\\\\s'
\\\\d+:\\\\d+:\\\\d+'|(?:select|and|or)\\\\s(?:(?:pg_)?sleep\\\\(\\\\d+
\\\\)|\\\\d+\\\\s?=\\\\s?(?:dbms_pipe\\\\.receive_message\\\\ ..." at 
REQUEST_COOKIES:sbjs_first. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules
/comodo_free/22_SQL_SQLi.conf"] [line "66"] [id "218500"] [rev "18"] 
[msg "COMODO WAF: SQLmap attack detected||website name|F|2"] [data 
"Matched Data: |||id=(none) found within REQUEST_COOKIES:sbjs_first: 
typ=typein|||src=(direct)|||mdm=(none)|||cmp=(none)|||cnt=(none)|||trm=
(none)|||id=(none)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "SQLi"] 
[hostname "website name"] [uri "/wp-login.php"] [unique_id "ZamB-
8j9IfDbYiJgRoahGwAAAAM"], referer:
```

When I visited some pages on the frontend it gives this error:
Server Error
403
Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this document.
That's what you can do
Reload Page Back to Previous Page Home Page

I wonder if this a real attack? or false positive

I was able to export the site to local. It seems working ok there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRS dev-on-duty here. Even if you don't use [CRS](https://coreruleset.org/) rules and this is a problem of `COMODO WAF` rules, I'll try to help. While searching for the cookie name `sbjs_first`, I found this GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/43681), which is an indication that this `sourcebuster` cookie looks legitimate. Maybe you'll even the solution to your problem in [one of the comments in this issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/43681#issuecomment-1893146364).
If this isn't the solution, you may need to tune the rules. Maybe you can also use [our (CRS) documentation on false positives and rule tuning](https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/).

Comment: Thank you! This helps. The comments of Github helped me in the right derection. I disabled the rule for now. It seems like this problem is coming from a recent update from Woocommerce. Only the weird thing was that even with all plugins disabled still the problem was there.